# S3 access policy to allow download to a specific IP address

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, acl

I'm trying to implement a batch virus scanner. I have a cron job set up to periodically scan unscanned files stored on S3. Whenever I try to wget the file, I get a `403`.

I've set up this policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "S3PolicyIPRestrict",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "IPAllow",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket/*",
            "Condition": {
                "IpAddress": {
                    "aws:SourceIp": "ip of my address/32"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: From where are you getting the IP address? Is it a public IP address or a private IP address? Does the policy work correctly if you remove the condition? (Not a good idea, but you can try it briefly for testing.) By the way, you should really limit the Action to `s3:GetObject` because that current policy permits _anything_, including deletion of buckets and objects.

Comment: removing the condition does not allow it to work. btw, i'm using wget, should i be using something else? Could it be because wget is interpreted as an http get and somehow CORS is taking over?

Comment: Try changing `"Principal": {"AWS": "*"}` into `"Principal": "*"`.

Answer (score 1):

Use the below bucket policy if you want to allow specfic ip address to access the files on s3 bucket.

```js
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "S3PolicyId1",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "IPAllow",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::<bucket>",
                "arn:aws:s3:::<bucket>/*"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "IpAddress": {
                    "aws:SourceIp": "<IP>/32"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```